# Passing chunked third-party API response through a WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, transfer-encoding

I am trying to consume an external API but the data that is returned is chunked:

```
Cache-control: max-age=7200
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
P3P: CP="Anything"
ApacheTracking: localhost
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

which is causing me issues. I can see the data in Fiddler, but when trying to return the data from a **Controller** from within a WebAPI project, nothing is returned. My code looks like this:

```
// Try to get our products
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(signedUrl);

    return Ok(response);
}
```

but the client application has no data. It returns a statusCode of 200 though.
Does anyone know how I can get my controller to return the chunked data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-assemble the body, the HttpClient does this for you.

You do need to read the response body though, because now you're trying to serialize an `HttpResponseMessage`, which it isn't really meant for.

Depending on what you actually want to return to the client, introduce your own Data Transfer Object, or simply return a string:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(signedUrl);

    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Ok(responseBody);
}
```

Alternatively, if your API method has a return type of `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, you could return the response of the API call directly (without wrapping it in `Ok()`, which will do the serialziation):

```
return response;
```

But I wouldn't do that, because you then can't control which header and body values your API will leak from the third-party API.